# Shiny and R combine three graphs into 1

Tags: r, shiny

I have developed a basic introductory shiny which downloads stock data and runs 3 technical indicators.

This is the code:

```
    library(shiny)
library(quantmod)
library(dygraphs)
library(TTR)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Simple Stock Charting App"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("symb", label = h3("Input a Valid Stock Ticker"), value = "GE") 
    ),
    selectInput("var", label = "bals", choices=list("RSI","Price","ADX")),


    ### uncomment for dygraphs chart
    mainPanel(dygraphOutput("plot"),dygraphOutput("plot2"),dygraphOutput("plot3"))
  )
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  dataInput <- reactive({
    prices <- getSymbols(input$symb, auto.assign = FALSE)
  })

  output$plot <- renderDygraph({renderPlot
    dygraph(Ad(dataInput())) %>%dyRangeSelector() 
  })

  output$plot2 <- renderDygraph({renderPlot
    dygraph((RSI(Ad(dataInput()), n = 14))) %>%dyRangeSelector()
  })
  output$plot3 <- renderDygraph({renderPlot
    dygraph((ADX(HLC(dataInput()),n = 14))) %>%dyRangeSelector()

  })
})


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I would like to know if it is possible the user to choose only of the three indicators each time. Currently, all three are shown but I know its possible to have one graph and based on the selection of the RSI, Value and ADX to change the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `switch` for what you want:

```
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)
library(dygraphs)
library(TTR)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Simple Stock Charting App"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("symb", label = h3("Input a Valid Stock Ticker"), value = "GE") 
    ),
    selectInput("var", label = "bals", choices=list("RSI","Price","ADX"))
  ),
  ### uncomment for dygraphs chart
  mainPanel(dygraphOutput("plot"))
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  dataInput <- reactive({
    getSymbols(input$symb, auto.assign = FALSE)
  })
  output$plot <- renderDygraph({
    data <- switch(input$var,"RSI" = RSI(Ad(dataInput()), n = 14),
                   "Price" = Ad(dataInput()),
                   "ADX" = ADX(HLC(dataInput()),n = 14))
    dygraph(data) %>%dyRangeSelector() 
  })
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image]